# How to create a new subdirectory and copy files into it? (C utility in Unix)

Tags: c, unix, directory, copy, utility

I'm making a utility in C under Unix. What functions would allow me to:

a) make a directory

b) copy a file into it

Can someone let me know what would work here or point me towards some documentation?

Comment: If the only thing your utility will do is those two operations it would be significantly easier to write it in /bin/sh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> a) make a directory

The `mkdir` library method

> b) copy a file into it

The `fopen`, `fread`, `fwrite` and `fclose` methods.

> ... point me towards some documentation?

The first place to look is section 3 of the online manual; e.g. `man 3 mkdir`.

Comment: How would I go about naming a sub directory named after its time of creation? Say I have the time ready in a string.

Comment: Do you know how to format or concatenate strings in C?  (Lookup `sprintf`, `strncpy`, `strncat`, etcetera ... or get a C textbook and read the chapters on string manipulation.) Form the pathname for the subdirectory using those techniques.